# Recorrer respuesta laravel con jquery y valir si existe valor dentro

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

quisiera por favor me orientaran sobre la siguiente situación...creo algo estoy haciendo mal.

Estoy en laravel 8

Controlador :

```
    public function index(){
    $permisos = Permission::all();
    return view('vista.index', compact('permisos'));
}
```

Mi vista.blade.php :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    jobs = @json($permisos);//Recibo la variable desde laravel
    console.log(jobs);
    console.log(jobs.includes('permiso_modulo_editar"')); //Validar que el valor enviado exista en el array proviente de laravel
});
</script>
```

La respuesta al mostrar lo que trae la variable $permisos desde el controlador :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta del "includes('permiso_modulo_editar')" para validar si existe o no dentro :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En resumen, necesito enviar la variable $permisos desde el controlador a mi index.blade.php y en la sección < script> con jquery validar si un valor cualquiera existe en su interior.**

Agradecere su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces la validación desde el controller?

Comment: Hola Jonathan, porque necesito validar especificamente un button generado con un datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función find de js

```
let permission = jobs.find(job => job.name === 'permiso_modulo_editar');

if(permission) {
    // Existe
}
```

Comment: Gracias Jonathan funciono perfecto, certero en la ayuda.!!!